# Is there a tool to monitor multiple composer based installations?

Tags: php, composer-php, monitoring

In `composer.json` and `composer.lock`, most informations about a php application's dependencies are described accurately.

I want to manage our installs (mostly CMS like TYPO3 and Craft) better and wonder if there is a tool that collects that information from multiple sites / servers and returns it in a structured, easy-to-read way. For example to answer the question: which of our sites use this xy extension.

It's ungooglable for me, but maybe you have a hint or know a script? The tool could run on cli, with a gui, locally or on a server, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

To monitor TYPO3 installations you could run extension [t3monitoring](https://github.com/georgringer/t3monitoring) in a single TYPO3 installation and collect information from other installations using [t3monitoring_client](https://github.com/georgringer/t3monitoring_client). This monitoring solution includes reports about extension versions in all monitored installations.

[There are also other monitoring solution avalaible for TYPO3](https://extensions.typo3.org/?L=0&id=1&tx_solr%5Bq%5D=monitoring).

Comment: Thanks – silly of me to have tagged it as TYPO3 question. I'm about to install t3monitoring, but I wonder about a generic composer based solution.